# Connecting to Charge point with the use of charge point wsdl from Central System

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Please note that that this question encountered while doing the implementation with the use of OCPP1.5 (Open charge point protocol 1.5).

Mentioned below are the steps I followed in order to connect with the charge point.

1. Chargepoint.wsdl was converted to the interface class with the use of
   wsdl.exe tool provided in Visual Studio.
2. Created the service class by implementing the service class with the
   charge  point interface created in step 1 and implemented the methods.
3. Created the Central System and added the Chargepoint.wsdl as the
   service reference to the Central System.
4. From the Central System, called the method implemented in the ChargePoint.

I have mentioned below the error occurred while calling the ChargePoint methods from the Central System

System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://192.168.40.221/ssamadhi/RCUControl.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

Server stack trace: 
   at

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Please mention where did I go wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try resetting iis.
Just open Windows PowerShell as Administrator and run `iisreset`.